# Using String.formatter to separate onto different lines

Tags: java, string, formatting

```
return String.format( "Name:\t%s", "\nHeight:", "\nWeight:",  name);
```

Firstly, why is "Weight:" not appearing at all?
Essentially, I need to print the following:

Name: John Smith

Height: 1.6m

Weight: 65kg

Height and Weight are stored in private fields.

How can I construct this string using String.formatter?
I've tried various methods and nothing seems to be working as intended.

Could somebody kindly construct this for me?

Comment: The first `String` is the "format", the other parameters are the values you want to substitute within the format

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) and [`String#format` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) for more details

Answer (score 1):

The first `String` is the "format", the other parameters are the values you want to substitute within the format

For example...

```
System.out.println(String.format( "Name:\t%s%nHeight:\t%.1fm%nWeight:\t%.1fkg", "Bruce", 1.6, 65.0));
```

prints...

```
Name:   Bruce
Height: 1.6m
Weight: 65.0kg
```

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) and [`String#format` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
return String.format("Name:\t%s\nHeight:\t%s\nWeight:\t%s", name, height, weight);
```

Comment: @MartinRand `\t` is a tab character `%s` a subsitiution marker to replace the given marker with the a `String` value based on the number markers/values